# Why are spaces / newlines missing in interactive kubectl bash session

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I've connected to a container inside my K8s cluster using:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec -ti <pod> -- bash
```

Next I'm looking at the content of files within the `/proc` virtual folder. So for looking at the environment variables defined for process with id 1, I do `cat /proc/1/environ`.

The problem is that the output is:

```
var1=valuevar2=valuevar3=value
```

instead of:

```
var1=value
var2=value
var3=value
```

The same thing happens for `cat /proc/1/cmdline`, as the output is

```
commandarg1arg2
```

instead of

```
command arg1 arg2
```

What's causing the newline and spaces to be omitted from the output, and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pieces of the environment can not be separated by Newlines, because a Newline character could be part of the environment string itself. Imagine an environment variable with name X, where its **value** is `AB\nY=Z`. You could not distinguish it from the case that you have two variables, X and Y.

The heart of the environment managements are the system calls [`getenv` and `setenv`](https://www.proggen.org/doku.php?id=c:lib:stdlib:setenv), which are for instance present in the C language. The value of the environment variable is a C-string, i.e. a sequence of bytes terminated by a NUL-byte. In fact, NUL is the only value which is not permitted inside the value of an environment variable.

Hence what your `cat` shows you is the environment definitions, separated by a NUL-byte.

Comment: I was going to ask how come the space in the `cmdline` file isn't shown, but realized that the command and parameters are most likely treated as null-terminated strings themselves, hence the output.

Comment: You may be able to use `cat /proc/1/cmdline | xargs -0 echo` to dump it out (with `-n 1`, one word to a line).  `xargs -0` isn't part of the POSIX standard but both the GNU tools and BusyBox support it.